# Knockout Mapping Ignore an Array of an Array

Tags: javascript, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am trying to ignore a property that is an array of an array. How do I specify this in the ignore object?

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {ignore: 'ArrayA.ArrayToIgnore'}, self);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options like observe, ignore and copy have limited capabilities when it comes to collections as far as I know. I do not know if there is a more robust solution, but I handled a similar sitution like below a while ago.

Sample Data (There are journals and each journal has currencies)

```
                var data = {
                    "journals": [{
                         "id": 1006,
                         "number": "2017/48",
                         "currencies": [{
                                   "id": 1,
                                   "code": "USD"
                    }]
                }]
            };
```

Mapping (We would like to ignore id property of currencies arrays of journals)

```
                var mappingOptions = {
                currencies: {
                    create: function (options) {
                        return ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, { ignore: ["id"] });
                    }
                }
            }
```

Initialization

```
var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions);
```